# Can Ansible task provisioned from Ansible run on a remote host without SSH?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ansible

Here is the problem statement:

Suppose I am on an EC2 instance A, and run an Ansible script which does the following tasks:

```
1. Create an EC2 instance B
2. SSH into it
3. Trigger an Ansible script which is on B, with the simple `ansible-playbook <pb_on_B>.yml` [B is being provisioned from an AMI]
```

So, **what will happen if the instance A gets terminated after task 3 gets started?**

**Will the Ansible script which is triggered in B, finish to completion?**

Comment: Why don't you test it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [W]hat will happen if the instance A gets terminated after task 3 gets started?
>
> Will the Ansible script which is triggered in B, finish to completion?

- You can't tell what would happen with 100% certainty.

  It depends on the shell configuration (for example `TMOUT` in bash), SSH daemon configuration (`TCPKeepAlive`, `ClientAliveInterval` parameters), timing, network conditions and whether A will close the session with (`FIN`) or drop without notifying A.
- Most likely the playbook execution would get interrupted.

  If SSH daemon on B cannot contact the SSH client on A (for example to print out Ansible execution log) and it gets the TCP `RST` packet, it will drop the session killing the SSH session's child processes, including the shell and `ansible-playbook`. However the session might also remain active until timeout and the playbook might finish before it occurs.
- If `ansible-playbook` executable was be called through the [`nohup` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) (or in a `screen` or `tmux` session), it won't be interrupted upon SSH session disconnect (and shell session closure).

  Note: when you use `nohup` the standard output will be redirected to a file `nohup.out`. Refer to the answers under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10408816/2947502) to learn the options.

  Also check [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148698/133107) on Unix.SE which describes the technicalities behind the command.

Comment: Thank you techraf. Always helpful :) . However, when I do `command: "nohup ansible-playbook -vvv /home/ec2-user/demo_provision.yml"`, I am getting a `failed to run command ‘ansible-playbook’: No such file or directory",` error.  So, is there someway I can run an ansible playbook with `nohup`?  Or am I using the `command` module wrong?

Comment: `which ansible-playbook` then try with full path.

Comment: Worked.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

> Can Ansible task provisioned from Ansible run on a remote host without SSH?

Yes, with [ansible-pull](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#ansible-pull):

> Should you want to invert the architecture of Ansible, so that nodes check in to a central location, instead of pushing configuration out to them, you can.
>
> The ansible-pull is a small script that will checkout a repo of configuration instructions from git, and then run ansible-playbook against that content.

Answer (score 1):

If the idea is to preserve an SSH session in instance B, without worrying about the life/death of instance A, you could try and run your ansible plays in tmux on instance B. Your workflow will be modified like this

1. Create an EC2 instance B
2. SSH into it
3. Instal tmux - `apt-get install tmux`
4. Start a tmux session `tmux new -s ansible`
5. Trigger an Ansible script which is on B, with the simple `ansible-playbook <pb_on_B>.yml`