# Run program on server forever without manually starting it

Tags: django, server, django-manage.py

I have created an application which resides on a server. The application uses Django to connect. So, if I want to access the web page I  have to run the following command to start the server -

```
 python manage.py runserver ip adress:port number
```

What is the way to keep it running all the time even after shutting down my computer?

But, I also want to save the logs of the application so that I can see it later and debug or just check the running of the program whenever I want to.

Comment: Use `tmux` or `nohup`

Comment: @itzMEonTV How are they used?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408816/how-do-i-use-the-nohup-command-without-getting-nohup-out

Comment: Simple but dirty way, run it as a background process (python manage.py runserver ip:port &) and log out of the server

Comment: @itzMEonTV that worked. Thanks :) I need another help. Can you please have a look at my post. i have edited it.

Comment: Use `tmux` then. You will have better control over your application.https://gist.github.com/MohamedAlaa/2961058

Comment: You **must not** use runserver in production. There's a whole section of the documentation about deployment; you should read it.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue by running the following command -

```
 nohup python manage.py runserver ip:port > Output.txt &
```

The log is getting saved in the Output.txt file.