# Anaconda Spyder not found but from terminal (ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, spyder

I installed Spyder editor with Anaconda. It works perfectly, I only have a question/doubt on the way I can open it.

I can open Spyder form terminal `spyder ...`, but Ubuntu does not find it among installed applications. Consequently, I cannot open it but from terminal. Whyle I can use `nohup spyder &` to separate Spyder from the terminal, this behavior seems strange to me. Should I just install a second Spyder through the package manager? Or is this expected to behave differently.

thank you, I guess this relates to possible software in general and hope it can be useful and interesting.

---

### edit

In the end I found **2 solutions**:

1) create a file `.desktop` https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102899/adding-an-icon-for-spyder-in-favourites-bar-in-ubuntu-18-04

2) open Spyder from terminal with the following function

I defined the following function in my *.bashrc*. Briefly, in this case, `nohup` prevents the terminal standard input from reaching Spyder, and redirects Spyder output signals to *nohup.out*.

To avoid the *nohup.out* file the function redirects all Spyder output (std output and error) to *dev/null*. *dev/null* discharges all it receives, therefore the file nohup.out wont be created, neither in the current directory nor in *dev/null*.

```
nopen() {
    nohup "$1" </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
}
```

[How do I use the nohup command without getting nohup.out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408816/how-do-i-use-the-nohup-command-without-getting-nohup-out)

Comment: instead of package manager try `conda install -c anaconda spyder` , it will automatically compiler spyder in system and u can use it on button click

Comment: great, thanks, once I have Spyder in the Anaconda3/bin directory what should I do to launch it? It seems to me that Spyder is there but ubuntu manager does not find it. I believe the question is how to add an external software to the ubuntu software. It is off topic but I ask here to close the question. I would be happy to accept the answer.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102899/adding-an-icon-for-spyder-in-favourites-bar-in-ubuntu-18-04 I think the solution is about creating a `.desktop` file for Spyder, the link above and others rated to .desktop discussed the topic. In the end I find my self to just call `nohup spyder &`, but it good to know.