# Log File Creation Issue from Jar Service

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot, rhel

I have a spring boot application deployed on RHEL 8. The app creates log files in specific folder and files based on the setting in the logback.xml file.

I am deploying the app as a service and I see that the logs are not getting created with the below configuration. The below script file is invoked from systemd process where this file is referenced.

```
#!/bin/sh 
SERVICE_NAME=My_Service_Name 
PATH_TO_JAR=/usr/Name_of_User/MyJavaApplication.jar 
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/My_Service_Name-pid 
case $1 in 
start)
       echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
  if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then 
       java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR      
                   echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME  
       echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."         
  else 
       echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
  fi
;;
stop)
  if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
         PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
         echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..." 
         kill $PID;         
         echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..." 
         rm $PID_PATH_NAME       
  else          
         echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."   
  fi    
;;    
restart)  
  if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then 
      PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);    
      echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ..."; 
      kill $PID;           
      echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";  
      rm $PID_PATH_NAME     
      echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."  
      java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR             
      echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME  
      echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."    
  else           
      echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."    
     fi     ;;
 esac
```

In the abovue script i even tried replacing

```
java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR
```

with

```
 nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >>/dev/null &
```

but no luck.

If i dont use this script and run the app from terminal like `java -jar MyApplication.jar` the log files do get created at the required location.

Answer (score 0):

```
nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Refer below for more information

[How do I use the nohup command without getting nohup.out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408816/how-do-i-use-the-nohup-command-without-getting-nohup-out)